# Why can't I close a pickle file?

Tags: python, pickle

I have been working on a classifier model, using GridSearchCV to find the best hyperparameters. I then pickled the model, and loaded it back (to save time everytime I have to run the notebook).

When I try to close it though, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'close'
```

This is my code:

```
# Save the Grid Search CV object as a pickle file
pickle.dump(knn_grid, open(r'./knn_grid_model.p', 'wb'))
# load the Grid Search CV object
knn_grid = pickle.load(open(r'./knn_grid_model.p', 'rb'))
# Close the file
knn_grid.close()
```

Any idea on how to overcome this? Will it be a big deal if I don't close the pickle file?

Comment: `knn_grid` isn't the file you got from `open`, it's the content `pickle` has loaded!

Comment: That's fine. This isn't like a file you are opening for modification that needs to be closed afterwards. You are just loading the model in as an object into a variable.

Comment: @Spencer Files should still be closed properly, otherwise other processes might become weird. The best practice would be `with open(...) as f: knn_grid = pickle.load(f)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`knn_grid` isn't a file, it's the `GridSearchCV` object that was unpickled.

However, your second question still stands:

> Will it be a big deal if I don't close the pickle file?

The way your code is written, the file may be left open until being garbage-collected or until the Python interpreter exits. Now, leaving a file open for *reading* shouldn't cause any problems, but leaving a file open for *writing* [could cause missing data](https://lerner.co.il/2015/01/18/dont-use-python-close-files-answer-depends/). So the best practice is to use a `with` statement to ensure that the content is written and the file is closed:

```
with open('./knn_grid_model.p', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(knn_grid, f)

with open('./knn_grid_model.p', 'rb') as f:
    knn_grid = pickle.load(f)
```

(Note that the r-strings don't make any difference in this case.)